# text within a box exceed when window size is reduced

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a website in which a div is having some texts and a background color.

```
<div class="info-box synopsis">
 Some text
</div>

.synopsis {
    background:#0d101c;
    text-indent:40px;
    opacity:0.6;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    line-height:25px;
    font-size:1.30;
    text-align:justify;
    border:1px solid #0d101c;
}
.info-box {
    padding:10px;
    color:#d2d2d2;
    font-size:1em;
}
```

It works fine when the screen is full width. But if we make the screen to smaller size, the texts within the div exceeds ! Please refer the images I have attached. Please help me in this regards.

URL : [Rajsree](http://rajsreeentertainment.com/)

[image: widescreen]

[image: smaller screen]

Comment: please give overflow:scroll when screen is smaller in your media query...

Comment: You will need to start positioning and sizing every element kind of forcefully, either with absolute, or if you don't have to support older browsers, flexbox model... `flex-direction: column;` to be exact. if The flexbox model is ok for you, let me know so I give you a complete solution.

Comment: @Mabedan Oh yes..its working in firefox !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the div element and asssign the class to body tag,

```
<div class="fullscreen-img"></div>
```

Assign class to body tab like this,

```
<body class="fullscreen-img">
```

Then Update the css of the class by modifying the background attribute.

```
.fullscreen-img {
background: url("2.jpg") no-repeat scroll;
```

remove the **center** attribute from background.

If you are facing difficulty to place the image in correct position, edit size of image to proper pixels.